# How does hibernate initialize an entity

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity which owns two `Transient` property `firstName` and `lastName`, and these two properties can be extracted from a third property `FullName` which is a user-defined type in the database.

Now I want to extract fill properties of the `firstName` and `lastName` once the entity is retrieved from the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;


    private FullName fullName;
    @Transient
    private String firstName;
    @Transient
    private String lastName;

    ...

    public void setFullName(FullName fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;

        this.firstName = fullName.getFirstName();
        this.lastName  = fullName.getLastName();
    }
}
```

However the `firstName` and the `lastName` is always null.

And I found that the `setFullName` is never stepped into when I open the debugger mode.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You've put @Id annotation at a field, effectively declaring that you want your JPA provider to use field access. Thus the setter is not invoked.

If you want to keep field access, you could remove the transient fields and add getters for firstName and lastName which delegate to fullName.

Comment: He could also simply avoid storing this redundant information in transient fields, and simply return fullName.getFirstName() from the getFirstName() getter.